# Shopware 6 - How to add a product or list of products to custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, shopware6

I'm really new to Shopware 6 and I'm learning it through videos and documentations.
I created a custom plugin, added a controller, service, etc... and created a page with it (As we learn the basics).
I searched everywhere on how to pass a product or list of products to the custom plugin and render it to the page, does anyone know how to do it? Which steps I should take to be able to do it?

Really appreciate any help :)

- Sorry if I misspelled something, my English is not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this question is way too general to really be answered. One could quote half of the documentation here. Without knowing specific details or what your problems during implementation may be, I really can only offer the most basic example.

You inject the product repository by referencing it in the service definition of your controller:

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Controller\MyCustomController">
    <argument type="service" id="sales_channel.product.repository"/>

    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
    <call method="setTwig">
        <argument type="service" id="twig"/>
    </call>
</service>
```

In the method of your route you use the injected repository to fetch the products and pass it to your template:

```php
class MyCustomController extends StorefrontController
{
    private SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/custom/route", name="my-plugin.frontend.custom-route", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function customPage(SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();

        // do something with the criteria, add filters etc...

        $products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);

        return $this->renderStorefront('@MyPlugin/storefront/custom/route/index.html.twig', ['products' => $products]);
    }
}
```

Then in your template you can iterate the products.

```
{# storefront/custom/route/index.html.twig #}

{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the basic example you shown me! At least now I have somewhere to start. Thx a lot!